# Drawing a crosshair in PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, shader, pyopengl

I have a working camera in a 3D scene in OpenGL, and I decided I want to draw a crosshair in the middle. To do that, I want to use a separate shader for the crosshair (and eventually, HUD) and the 3D scene. I managed to make something work using `glDrawArrays` and a VBO with the line vertices in it.

The problem with this setup is that the cross extends all the way to the borders of the window, even though I specified small coordinates so that it is just in the center of the screen.

Here are my shaders (in order, vertex shader and fragment shader):

```
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 0, 0);
}
```

```
#version 450 core

out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {
    FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

As you can see, they are extremely simple and do literally nothing with the coordinates. The drawing process looks something like this:

```
crosshair = np.array([
  -0.02, 0,
   0.02, 0,
   0, -0.02,
   0,  0.02], dtype = 'float32')
vbo_2d, vao_2d = glGenBuffers(1), glGenVertexArrays(1)

glBindVertexArray(vao_2d)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_2d)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, crosshair, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

while not window.check_if_closed():
    #render 3d stuff with another shader program and other vbos ad vaos

    glBindVertexArray(0)

    shader_program_2d.use()
    glBindVertexArray(vao_2d)
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 4)

    #swap buffers etc.
```

This is what my window looks like:

[image: OpenGL Screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's the entire code if you need it, with the same vertex and fragment shaders for the GUI as in the post: https://pastebin.com/x4ya81tj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the computation of the [Homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) clip space coordinate in the vertex shader. The normalized device space coordinate is computed by dividing the `.xyz` components of `gl_Position` by it's `.w` component ([Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide)).
Since the `.w` component is 0, the resulting coordinates become infinite (except the coordinate itself is 0).

<s>`gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 0, 0);`</s>

```c
gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Hmm, very interesting that it doesn't give some form of math error... I was dividing by 0! Thanks!

Comment: @Parashoo Do you want to get a runtime error for each vertex which is processed? GLSL may support the special values _-Inf_, _Inf_. See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 2.3.4.1 Floating-Point Computation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=43&zoom=100,168,366)